# Check for XML parents in Loop AS3

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3

Is it possible to check to see if all XML node parents exist in a loop of some sort? Let's say I have a reference along the lines of:

```
myXML.sectionOne.subSectionOne.subsubSectionFive.subsubsubSectionTwo.name
```

What I am finding is that not only might the `name` node not exist, but any number of the parent nodes might not exist as well. So what I've been stuck doing is something along the lines of:

```
if(myXML.sectionOne != undefined)
{
    if(myXML.sectionOne.subSectionOne != undefined)
    {
        if(myXML.sectionOne.subSectionOne.subsubSectionFive != undefined)
        {
            if(myXML.sectionOne.subSectionOne.subsubSectionFive.subsubsubSectionTwo != undefined)
            {
                if(myXML.sectionOne.subSectionOne.subsubSectionFive.subsubsubSectionTwo.name != undefined)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have here is badly designed XML structure

Comment: I would agree, unfortunately I am not the one generating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a recursive function to check each node's [localName()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#localName%28%29):

```
var xml:XML = <root>
<sectionOne>
    <subSectionOne>
        <subsubSectionFive>
            <subsubsubSectionTwo>
                <name>bam!</name>
            </subsubsubSectionTwo>
        </subsubSectionFive>
    </subSectionOne>
</sectionOne>
</root>;

trace(hasNodeByName(xml,"name"));

function hasNodeByName(xml:XML,nodeName:String):Boolean{
    if(xml.localName() == nodeName) return true;//check root
    for each(var node:XML in xml.*){//check each node on 1st level
        if(node.localName() == nodeName) return true;
        else if(node.length() > 0) return hasNodeByName(node,nodeName);//we need to go deeper!
    }
    return false;   
}
```